# Не отправляются данные из php запроса в sql таблицу

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Запрос php, нужно отправить данные из именованного массива
сам массив:

```
$we = array(
    "Address" => "Петру Мовила 20",
    "Vk_link" => "https://vk.com/yarik_daun",
    "Inst_link" => "https://www.instagram.com/_omtek_/",
    "Facebook_link" => "https://www.facebook.com/"
);
```

запрос:

```
<?php
include "config.php";

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "contact_us_sql");

if(!$connect){
    echo "Ошибка подключения: " . mysqli_connect_error(); 
    exit();
}; 

//Обновление данных о нас
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "contact_us_sql");

$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `soc_contact`(`address`, `vk_link`, `inst_link`, `facebook_link`) VALUES ('{$we['Address']}','{$we['Vk_link']}','{$we['Inst_link']}','{$we['Facebook_link']}");
```

Comment: а можно спросить?

Comment: закрыть вообще надо было опечаткой, а про инъекции в коммент. по факту тут в закрывающая одинарная кавычка в конце отсутствует.